# How to get Window Username after deploying silvelight app. It display "DefaultPool" as Window Username

Tags: asp.net, wcf, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I am trying to get Window username in silver light Application. I open aspx page from my silver light page on button click event using below code:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btntest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("WebForm1.aspx", UriKind.Relative)); 
    }
}
```

Now on WebForm1.aspx, I am trying to get Window Username using below code:

```
 public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = System.Environment.UserName;
        }
     }
```

When I run my silverlight project in my local machine, It gives right Window username in Label1 and it works fine. But When I deploy my appication in IIS and check then It display "DefaultPool" in my Label1.

Can any one help to solve this issue?

Is there any setting in ISS I have to do to get Window UserName?

Thanks,
Hitesh

Answer (score 0):

Always test your code in IIS, even on your local machine.

Just like your question yesterday, the code is run on the server machine. So it will return your username on your test box if you run it in Visual Studio instead of IIS and it will return the name of the user IIS is using to host your page or service otherwise.

Why do you want to get the user name? Getting part of the user credential of the client is really not the business of a web application, no matter what technical background.

If you want to get user credentials in a web application, ask the user. If you think you are on a trust level that makes the user want to send his data automatically, create a real application. That's a lot less trouble than a web application where you have to support all kinds of devices and have to cope with all kinds of limitations that are normal for applications we open in our browsers daily.

Comment: Hi Nvoigt, I am trying to trusted login and native login in my silvelight app based on user setting screen in which user set about login pattern which he want. If user set native then i check normal username and password saved in database while registration and when user set trusted then we get Window username to check for Login.

Comment: @Hitesh What if I create a user named Hitesh on my machine? Does that mean I am you?

Comment: I only get username from Window Username and display in txtUsername and then user enter password in txtPassword then We check into database with this login credentials.

Comment: @Hitesh You cannot get the windows username from the client machine. You are not in that kind of trust scenario with a web application. If you need that kind of trust (and I don't think your scenario needs it) you must write a normal windows application.

Comment: My code will works fine if I set Window Authentication Enable and Anonymous Authentication Disable. But In my case, I want both Enable then it gives ISUR as a username.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not getting the username for the user accessing your application is because you are using a method that retrieves the context of the currently logged on user, in the case of a web application, you are retrieving the user context of the application pool.

system.environment.username "Gets the user name of the person who is currently logged on to the Windows operating system."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username(v=vs.110).aspx

You may want to research mixed mode authentication to allow both forms and windows authentication as well as single sign on if you want NTLM (windows) authentication to take place without prompting the user for their details.